# I am an Indian citizen. Do I need a visa to visit Thailand as a tourist?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, paperwork, thailand

I am an Indian passport holde. I want to travel from India to Bangkok. What are the requirements and documents I must have/obtain to lawfully visit Thailand?

Comment: What's your citizenship? How do you plan on travelling?

Comment: iam an indian....um i wanted to go there ..my aunt is in there and wanted to visit her..help me out plz

Comment: By "how" I mean what mode of transport? Plane/Bus/Train/Boat?

Answer (score 3):

Indian passport holders can visit Thailand without visa for 15 days. You can collect your visa on arrival.

http://www.thaiembassy.org/mumbai/contents/files/services-20150825-140852-485893.pdf

But you must follow these rules

> **Visa on Arrival**
>
> For passengers who would like to apply for Visa on Arrival  to travel
>   in Thailand, there are two service counters  provided by Suvarnabhumi
>   airport before reaching to  the Immigration on 2nd level. The details
>   and required  documents are listed as follows:
>
> 1. Hold the citizenship of a country on the list issued by th e minister
>      under the consent of  the Council of Ministers of  Thailand. (India is
>      listed see the pdf)
> 2. Aim to enter Thailand for tourism for the period of not exceeding 15
>      days.
> 3. Submit one 4 x 6 cm. headshot photo taken no longer than 6 months.
> 4. Does not fall into the category of aliens prohibited from entering
>      Thailand under the Immigration law.
> 5. Possess the return ticket within 15  days.(confirmed return air
>      ticket)
> 6. Truthfully notify the verifiable places to  stay in Thailand. (proof
>      of hotel booking)
> 7. Present evidence of adequate finance, not less than 20,000 Baht
>      (700US$) per person and 40,000 Baht  (1400US$) per family.
> 8. Possess a passport or travel document with validity not less than 6
>      months.
> 9. Pay 1,000 Baht for the visa fee (Thai currency only)

**Official Thailand Government Links**

http://www.mfa.go.th/main/en/services/4908/15380-Questions-&-Answers-on-Thai-Visa.html
http://www.thaiembassy.org/mumbai/en/services/647/59474-Visa-on-Arrival.html

Answer (score 1):

To apply for a VOA - Visa on Arrival, as a citizen of India ....

You need your passport of course.

You need a round trip ticket departing Thailand within 15 days of arrival (only a 15 day stay allowed on a VOA).

You need to prove you have at least 10,000 baht per person or 20,000 baht for a family, in your possession.

You need to pay 1000 baht fee for your VOA when you reach Bangkok.

If you want to stay longer, you need to apply for a tourist visa from the Thai Embassy in India before traveling.

Comment: References for those requirements (although they sound pretty feasible)?

Comment: @CMaster - References: nearly 30 years of working in tourism organizing tours to Thailand. Though pbu's post would indicate that the cash requirement has been raised for India citizens, as it is still 10K for most other VOA qualified nationalities.

Comment: The changes are exactly why I wanted to see an offical link, rather than a personal-knowledge statement - because details for these things do change, yet you find out advice all over the internet.

Comment: @CMaster - The Thai Embassy in Delhi lists 10k as the requirement for a VOA, as do several other Thai Embassies.  It seems that only the Mumbai website lists 20k, so one has to wonder if that is a typo (20k is the requirement for a tourist visa). http://newdelhi.thaiembassy.org/en/visa-on-arrival-en/